# one line if statement

Tags: python, if-statement

I have the following code

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
b = [1, 3, 3, 4, 5, 7]
counter = 0
for x,y in tuple(zip(a, b)):
    if x==y:
        counter += 1
```

How do I write that in one line? I tried this `counter+= 1 if ((x==y) for (x, y) in tuple(zip(a, b))) else None` but it adds 1 to the counter and that's all.

Comment: Python is not designed for one-liners; instead, it's designed for clarity and maintainability -- and as described in the "*practical*, answerable" criteria in https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, Stack Overflow is very much focused on _practical_ questions -- if you want to make things shorter with no regard to whether doing so is actually going to result in maintainable code, [codegolf.se] is thataway.

Comment: It is a pratical question, how to do something in one line. A non-pratical question would be 'Is this code good?' or 'How can I improve this code?'. And sadly, there are uses for one liners in python, due to it's lack of suport of multi-lines lambdas. So, using @tdelaney response, I can see someone using `lambda a, b: sum(x == y for x, y in zip(a, b))` somewhere.

Comment: for (x, y) in zip(a, b): counter+= (x==y)

Answer (score 3):

You can leverage `True == 1` and `False == 0`

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> b = [1, 3, 3, 4, 5, 7]
>>> counter = sum(_a==_b for _a,_b in zip(a,b))
>>> counter
4
```

Comment: I would probably still use `x` and `y`, as in `sum(x == y for x, y in zip(a, b))` since it looks better IMO, but logically the solution is the best one-liner possible.

Comment: @JoãoHaas - Right. The important thing is that the generator has its own namespace so its `a` doesn't mask the global namespace `a`. But using the same name can be awkward and make a reader scratch their head. Like `[a*2 for a in a]`. Best, I think is longer names in the first place so that these temporary variables are easy to distinguish. If those lists were `foo` and `bar`, then we'd have `sum(f==b for f,b in zip(foo, bar))` which is easier to read. I used the underscores to highlight that they are different than the a,b lists.

Answer (score 0):

Addition over an iterable can be expressed with [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum):

```
counter = sum(1 if x==y else 0 for x,y in zip(a, b))
```

Comment: Variant: `counter = sum(int(x==y) for x,y in zip(a, b))`

Comment: Variant: `counter = sum(1 for x,y in zip(a, b) if x==y)`

Answer (score 0):

you can try this,

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
b = [1, 3, 3, 4, 5, 7]
counter=len([x for x,y in zip(a,b) if x==y])
```

Another way,

```
counter=sum(map(lambda x:x[0]==x[1],zip(a,b)))
```